# Facebook page posts edge returns same result as feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of page posts only, using the {page_id}/posts edge with the v2.10 API.

But for whatever reason, it simply returns the exact same result as {page_id}/feed - which includes status updates (they use the 'stories' tag, rather than 'message')

The API clearly states I can use the /posts edge to get only public posts, yet it's not behaving how it should.

What are my options? Is there a way to exclude stories from the /feed edge?

Comment: are you really talking about pages, or user profiles? if the behaviour is not as expected, you should file a bug.

Comment: _“The API clearly states I can use the /posts edge to get only public posts”_ - no, it doesn’t state _that_. What it does say, is _“only the posts that were published by this page”_ This is to filter out posts made by users to the page, or posts that would show up in the page feed because the page was tagged in a post made by a different entity on their own timeline.

Comment: @CBroe ah crapola! So I'm going to have to go through the feed myself and remove anything that isn't a 'post'?